# How to explode two variables with PHP

Tags: php

I was expecting that the explode function of the following string

```
$lines[1]="Start_time= ". $ST. ':' . $STIMI."\n" ;
```

would give me `Array[0]= Start_time,  Array[1]= $ST,  Array[2]= :,  Array [3]= $STIMI`

But the explode function gives me: `Array[0]= Start_time  Array[1]= $ST:$STIMI`

`$ST` and `$STIMI` are both variables. Any idea how to fix this

Comment: show us how you call explode

Comment: $STIME=explode(" ",$lines[1]);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [explode](http://php.net/explode) function takes a parameter by which to explode the string. Presuming you are using a blank space you will need to add a blank space on either side of your colon.

```
$lines[1]="Start_time= ". $ST. ' : ' . $STIMI."\n" ;
```

Comment: @MaryE good, just so you understand, the explode function will take any string you pass as a second parameter, regardless of if it's passed in as a variable, and split it using the string passed in to the first parameter as a split point. As you passed in a blank space as a split point, your string will be split at every blank space. Make sense?

Answer (score 1):

Explode by using the ":" separator as opposed to " "

```
$STIME=explode(":", $lines[1]);
```

Mind that if you have ":" in your strings it will mess up your algorithm.